# Change colour of Switch and Picker from ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I have implemented MVVM pattern with property for colour `SColor`. This property is attached to Picker.

```
    <Switch IsToggled="{Binding IsCounted}" OnColor="{Binding SColor}"></Switch>

    <Entry Text="{Binding TimeS}" BackgroundColor="{Binding SColor}"></Entry>

    <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding PColors}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedColor}" 
            ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding ColorName}" BackgroundColor="{Binding SColor}" 
            Background="{Binding SColor}"></Picker>
```

In ViewModel:

```
private Color sColor;
public Color SColor
{
  get => this.sColor;
  set
  {
    this.sColor = value;
    this.OnPropertyChanged();
  }
}

private ColorModel selectedColor;
public ColorModel SelectedColor
{
  get => this.selectedColor;
  set
  {
    this.selectedColor = value;
    this.OnPropertyChanged();
  }
}
```

and ColorModel.cs

```
  public class ColorModel
  {
    public string ColorName { get; set; }
    public string ColorHex { get; set; }
  }
```

For some reason Colour of Switch and Picker are not changing from ViewModel where Entry background colour does. See screenshot below. I have selected Red colour and Entry backgound clour has been updated, but Switch and Picker are not. For Switch I have noticed, that after hovering mouse on, colour does change and for Picker itself switching between pages updates selected colour. Is it MAUI bug or feature or I am doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: Read about DataTriggers.

Comment: If you still want color binding, you can copy paste this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/binding-mode?view=net-maui-7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For some reason Colour of Switch and Picker are not changing from
> ViewModel where Entry background color does.

I did a test on my side,the `OnColor` of Switch will update automatically.

And the `BackgroundColor` of both `Entry` and `Picker` will not update automatically.

From the source code of [Switch](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/src/Core/Switch.cs) in maui,we could find that:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty OnColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(OnColor), typeof(Color), typeof(Switch), null,
            propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
            {
                ((IView)bindable)?.Handler?.UpdateValue(nameof(ISwitch.TrackColor));
            });

    public Color OnColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(OnColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OnColorProperty, value); }
    }
```

it means that property `OnColor` is a `BindableProperty`,so if we change the value of the binded property `OnColor`, the UI will update automatically.

```
  <Switch IsToggled="{Binding IsCounted}" OnColor="{Binding SColor}"></Switch>
```

And if we review the source code of [Picker](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/src/Core/Picker.cs) and [Entry](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/src/Core/Entry.cs), we will find that there is no BindableProperty called `BackgroundColor` in both views.

So, if we use binding method to update `BackgroundColor`, the UI will not refresh automatically.

You can create new features about this [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose).

Of course,if you want to change the background color, you can try to use [Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/triggers?view=net-maui-7.0).

Thanks for your support and feedback.

Comment: This is actually a Net Maui bug. It has been submitted and they already created a pull request with the fix.